# What's the best way to update a whole table in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Based on the content of a hash I want to:

- create new records with the elements that are not yet in the table
- delete the records that are not in the hash
- update the attributes of the records in commom

I'm trying to sync my table with the hash (which is the data I'm getting from the FLickr API)

The Photos table looks like:

```
#  id              :integer         not null, primary key
#  photoset_id     :integer
#  flickr_photo_id :integer
#  url             :string(255) 
#  private         :boolean         default(FALSE)
#  created_at      :datetime
#  updated_at      :datetime
```

And the hash has the same attributes:

`:flickr_photo_id, :url and :private`

The way I'm doing right now:

```
photoset.photo.destroy_all
photoset.photo.build(flickr_photos)
photoset.save!
```

Is this a better way to do this without deleting and rebuilding the whole table?

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing things off the cuff - perhaps you can do a merge and then do a destroy on whatever elements don't exist in the flickr list.  This sounds more like 'how do I deal with arrays/hashes question'.

Comment: Sounds good. Doing an update_all with the merged hash should work, right? Thanks a lot.